# Declare Field as Parameterized List Using java assist

Tags: java, javassist

We can declare field like following code.

```
evalClass.addField(CtField.make("private java.util.List abc;", evalClass));
```

How can we declare field `List<String> abc` using java assist?

Answer (score 2):

Done little bit research on CtField class. we can set through setGenericSignature.

```
        CtField f = new CtField(pool.get(List.class.getCanonicalName()), "abc", evalClass);
        f.setGenericSignature(getGenericSignature(relatedClass));
        evalClass.addField(f);

    private String getGenericSignature(Class relatedClass) throws BadBytecode {
        String fieldSignature = "L" + List.class.getCanonicalName().replace(".", "/") + "<L" + String.class.getCanonicalName().replace(".", "/") + ";>;";
        return  SignatureAttribute.toClassSignature(fieldSignature).encode();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, generics are not supported by Javassist.
From the Javassist [documentation](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#generics):

> **Generics**
>
> The lower-level API of Javassist fully supports generics introduced by
>   Java 5. On the other hand, the higher-level API such as CtClass does
>   not directly support generics. However, this is not a serious problem
>   for bytecode transformation.
>
> The generics of Java is implemented by the erasure technique. After
>   compilation, all type parameters are dropped off. For example, suppose
>   that your source code declares a parameterized type Vector:
>
> ```
> Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();   
> String s = v.get(0);
> ```
>
> The compiled bytecode is equivalent to the following code:
>
> ```
> Vector v = new Vector();   
> String s = (String)v.get(0);
> ```
>
> **So when you
>   write a bytecode transformer, you can just drop off all type
>   parameters. Because the compiler embedded in Javassist does not
>   support generics**, you must insert an explicit type cast at the caller
>   site if the source code is compiled by Javassist, for example, through
>   CtMethod.make(). No type cast is necessary if the source code is
>   compiled by a normal Java compiler such as javac.

So you can basically use the method you wrot in your question in order to add a List without generic specification and that's gonna do the work